# $ bundle install The unmet dependencies are: * bundler (~> 1.0), dependency of rails-3.0.20, unsatisfied by bundler-2.4.20

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
$ bundle install
```

> Installing bcrypt-ruby 3.0.1 with native extensions
>
> Installing json 1.7.7 with native extensions
>
> Installing eventmachine 1.0.0 with native extensions
>
> Your lockfile doesn't include a valid resolution. You can fix this by
> regenerating your lockfile or manually editing the bad locked gems to
> a version that satisfies all dependencies. The unmet dependencies are:
>
> bundler (~> 1.0), dependency of rails-3.0.20, unsatisfied by
> bundler-2.4.20 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
> extension.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg7DV.png)

I'm getting this error, can you help me please?